# ANTLR4 - Quoted and non-quoted strings to support at the same time

Tags: antlr4, lexer

What I am trying to achieve is to develop a grammar that would parse the following two lines in the same way:

```
1. "Bucket 1" = "1 item placed", "3 items removed"
2. Bucket 2 = 2 items placed, 6 items removed
```

So, a line starts with an ordinal number, then an element name goes - 'Bucket 1' and 'Bucket 2'. Also, a bucket has one or more values separated by a comma.

The issue is that the data can come enclosed with double quotes (line #1 above) and without the quotes (as shown in line #2). I can figure grammars for each of the lines separately but can not develop a grammar that would parse them both.

```
grammar Test;
doc : element+ EOF; 

element: ordinal element_name EQUAL element_values '\n';
element_name : STRING ;
element_values: STRING (COMMA STRING)+; 

ordinal : NUMBER ;
COMMA: ',' ;
EQUAL: '=' ;
NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+ ;
STRING : '"' (EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"' ; 
// STRING : ('"' (EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"') | ~('"'|',')+ ;


fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   OctalEscape
    ;
fragment
OctalEscape
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;
WS : [ .\t]+ -> skip ;
```

I played with *STRING* rule above trying to make it handle both cases but with no luck. If I enable the commented out version of *STRING* rule, then I get a *line 1:0 missing NUMBER at '4. '* parser error which is confusing as I thought that NUMBER rule should be caught since it goes first.

Is that a wrong assumption? Can you please explain why it does not get caught?